# How to drive media queries with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I would like to find a way to make an algorithm that changes my media queries zoom % depending on the resolution size, for example, every time the width decreases 100px the zoom factor increases by 10%.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
   html {
       -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
       zoom: 0.75;
       zoom: 0%;
   }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1904px) {
   html {
       -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
       zoom: 0.75;
       zoom: 73%;
   }
}
```

Comment: zoom is a non standrad feature and probably shouldn't be used in production: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: Also, can you not just write media queries for each 100px reduction?  If you get js involved, you will get the flash of unstyled content whilst the js loads and kicks in

Comment: Hi, @BriannaDevos. You will get a lot more feedback if you reformat your question. Since you are new here, I would recommend reading ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That will help you getting better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch any screen adjustments made by users, like this...

```
 document.body.onresize=function(){MyAdjustments();};
```

And then call the function to apply the necessary logic...

```
function MyAdjustments(){

 var W=screen.width, H=screen.height;

 // You've now got the new resolution so take whatever decisions are needed.

 }
```